# Join queries in Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join, schema

I'm having a lot of issues writing this query. Can someone please advise!

Select all from bookings table where

bookings.product_id = product.id

then based on the return, i want to say if a field in the returned results (created_at) is greater than "7" then return 1 otherwise return 0.

Comment: which database are you using? mysql?oracle?mssql?other?

Comment: im using mysql - phpmyadmin

Comment: @Robson How does it matter? the DB query will be same

Comment: @GauravDave you are right, I was thinking about giving him the plain SQL query

Comment: @Robson Okay, but that wasn't useful in case of laravel.

Comment: @GauravDave sure, I noticed that with your first comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = DB::table('product')->join('bookings','bookings.product_id','=','product.id')->get();
if($data->created_at > 7){
  return 1;
}else{
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the query which will work for you

Comment: This query seems to work but whenever i try to reference this in the blade view i get a Trying to get property of non-object error. In the blade view i have the if statement. The query is contained in my routes file and passes into the page where im trying to reference it

Comment: first of all writing a query in route is a super bad practice.what you wanna do is create a controller point your route to a function of that controller write the above code in the function and pass the data to the view using with.

Comment: i know but i can pass other variables through this and it isn't a problem. i just need it to reference the right field from the table but it is saying there is no object of any field name returned. is there any way i can check what the query returns?

Comment: before the if statement do this echo '<pre>'; print_r($data->toArray()); echo '<pre>'; exit;

Answer (score 1):

Assumption:- you wanted to write booking.product_id = product_id
If my assumption is correct below answer might help you.

```
with temp as(
Select * from bookings where
bookings.product_id = product_id)
select case when temp.created_at > 7 then 1 else 0
        end as comparison
from temp;
```

Let me know if my assumption was incorrect so that I can give you right answer.